# Jest Test cases not covering optional chaining

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, testcase

I am writing test cases for my NestJS application in Jest.
How do we cover optional chaining branches ?
Here is my code

```
async getUsers(query: GetUsersQueryDto): Promise<UsersDto[]> {
const findWhereOptions: FindOptionsWhere<Users> = { is_deleted: false };
if (query?.role_id) {
  findWhereOptions.role_id = query.role_id;
} else {
  const adminRole = await this.rolesService.getRoleByName(Role.SUPER_ADMIN);
  findWhereOptions.role_id = Not(adminRole.id);
}

const list = await this.usersRepository.find({
  where: findWhereOptions,
  relations: { role: true, facility: true },
});
return UsersService.convertToDto(list);
```

}

and my Test case is

```
it("getUsers: should return users data", async () => {
    jest.spyOn(repository, "find").mockResolvedValue([validMockUser]);
    const result = await service.getUsers({ role_id: "1" });
    expect(result).toEqual([validMockResponseUser]);
  });
```

**This is the coverage of the function**

[image: This is the coverage of the function]

How do I cover `query?.role_id` branch?

Answer (score 0):

Found the hack! (Not sure it is a hack though)

wrote 2 test cases

1. Pass argument to the function

```
it("getUsers: should return users data", async () => {
   jest.spyOn(repository, "find").mockResolvedValue([validMockUser]);
   const result = await service.getUsers({ role_id: "1" });
   jest
     .spyOn(rolesService, "getRoleByName")
     .mockResolvedValue({ id: "1", role_name: "user" });
   expect(result).toEqual([validMockResponseUser]);
 });
```

2. Do not pass argument to the function

```
it("getUsers: should return users data", async () => {
   jest.spyOn(repository, "find").mockResolvedValue([validMockUser]);
   const result = await service.getUsers();
   expect(result).toEqual([validMockResponseUser]);
 });
```